FHIR query using _type and common search parameters
I'm using the Azure FHIR service R4 and trying to find all device and service requests that are based on a particular care plan. I ran the following request:
{{fhirurl}}/?_type=DeviceRequest,ServiceRequest&based-on=CarePlan/91beb13f-340c-40a0-9f76-f4434b5fe6e4

but obtained the following error:
{
    "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
    "id": "58d48f8f9f50a2ff551718b007a3aca1",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2024-07-17T12:05:05.3195628+00:00"
    },
    "issue": [
        {
            "severity": "error",
            "code": "invalid",
            "diagnostics": "Search parameter 'based-on' is not common for 'DeviceRequest' and 'ServiceRequest'."
        }
    ]
}

As far as I can see, both DeviceRequest and ServiceRequest resources have a "based-on" search parameter. Am I missing something, or is Azure FHIR service not supporting this?
Note that I can't search for the careplan itself using revinclude because the above is used following a delete event for the care plan.

To answer this

"Azure FHIR service not supporting this?"

you could check the server's metadata by going to {{fhirurl}}/metadata
Assuming the server doesn't support this type of search, one way around it would be to perform seperate searches
{{fhirurl}}/?_type=ServiceRequest&based-on=CarePlan/91beb13f-340c-40a0-9f76-f4434b5fe6e4


{{fhirurl}}/?_type=DeviceRequest&based-on=CarePlan/91beb13f-340c-40a0-9f76-f4434b5fe6e4

and then combine the results.
If this is not something you'd like to do then another option is defining a custom SearchParameter that provides the functionality you need. See how to create a custom search parameter in Azure FHIR Server here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/how-to-do-custom-search
Hope these help point you in the right direction

Thanks for the feedback.
I did check the Azure FHIR service instance I have (https://hdswdevrvtdevuks1-fhir-dev-rvt-dev-1.fhir.azurehealthcareapis.com/metadata) and both resources (DeviceRequest and ServiceRequest) support the based-on search attribute. That's the reason I don't understand why my search on both resources doesn't.
I didn't know about SearchParameter. That might come in handy in the future... :)

You're welcome. I suspect what is happening is that the based-on might be supported for individual resources but perhaps not when combined, this is why i think a custom SearchParameter might be the way forward, but I stand corrected.
